# DisplayMemberPath usage causing unwanted itemsource to Combbox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am using a ComboBox as follows:

Code-behind:

```
List<Client> clients = GetClients();
ComboBox1.ItemsSource = clients;
```

The Client class contains the properties `ClientID`, `ClientName`. The `DisplayMemberPath` property of ComboBox is set to `ClientName` and the `SelectedValuePath` is set to `ClientID`.

When I implement this, the combobox upon expanding shows the full Client class name, though it is expected to show all the ClientNames. It shows `Ezone.Entities.Types.Client` for all the rows in the dropdown. Can one of you explain this and give me a fix for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may also post the Client class declaration and the relevant part of the CombBox XAML.

Comment: Just a guess, but make sure that `ClientName` and `ClientID` are *public properties* in class Client. Neither fields nor non-public properties will do.

Answer (score 0):

Class Client-

```
    public class Client:INotifyPropertyChanged
            {
                private string _ClientName;

                public string ClientName
                {
                    get { return _ClientName; }
                    set { _ClientName = value;
                   OnPropertyChanged("ClientName");
                    }
                }
                private string _ClientID;

                public string ClientID
                {
                    get { return _ClientID; }
                    set { _ClientID = value;
                  OnPropertyChanged("ClientID");
                }
                }
            }

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Called when [property changed].
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="PropertyName">Name of the property.</param>
        private void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
            }
        }
```

CodeBehind-

```
List<Client> clients = GetClients();
            ComboBox1.ItemsSource = clients;

    public List<Client> GetClients()
            {
               List<Client> lst=new List<Client>();
               Client obj = new Client();
               obj.ClientName = "asd";
               obj.ClientID = "1";
               lst.Add(obj);
               return lst;
            }
```

View Xaml-

```
<ComboBox Name="ComboBox1" Width="100" Height="30" DisplayMemberPath="ClientName" SelectedValuePath="ClientID"/>
```

Comment: The above code still doesn't solve the problem. Interestingly, this problem is occuring only when certain WPF themes are applied, 'WhistlerBlue' theme in this case. If I couldn't solve this problem, I shall have to switch to a less favorable theme in which this problem doesn't arise.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is that WPF doesn't know what to display... implement the `ToString()` method in your `Client` class and you'll see this instead of the fully qualified name.

There could be a number of reasons why the `ComboBox` does not recognise your class... there may be a spelling mistake, or the properties that you mentioned might not be visible (public), etc.